# Check inheritance of prototype, rather than instance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Lets say I have:

```
function Pet(){}
Pet.prototype.breathe = function(){}
```

And

```
function Cat(){}
```

I then go along and do:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Pet.prototype)
Cat.prototype.purr = function(){}
```

I know I can check

```
var cat = new Cat()
console.log(cat instanceof Pet); //true
```

But how can I check if the function `Cat` is *going to be* an instance of `Pet` without instantiating it?

The most simple and hacky way I can think of is...

```
Pet.prototype.$$pet = true
```

And then check

```
console.log(Cat.prototype.$$pet) //true
```

But that doesn't seem very nice because I can just go along and do

```
Cat.prototype.$$pet = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can actually use

```
Cat.prototype instanceof Pet
```

MDN's examples of instanceof shows this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof